# Format div using css

Tags: javascript, css, sencha-touch, extjs

How can I format a div inside html in Sencha? I have the following properties I'd like implemented on my html

```
#logo{
    position:absolute;
    top:20%;
    left:0%;
}
```

A sample of my Sencha code is here

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Sencha',
    launch: function() {
        Ext.create("Ext.tab.Panel", {
            fullscreen: true,
            tabBarPosition: 'bottom',items: [
                {
                    title: 'Home',
                    iconCls: 'home',
                    cls: 'home',
                    html: [
                       '<div id="logo">My logo here</div>'
                    ].join("")
                }
               ]
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give it as inline css

```
<div id="logo" style="position:absolute;top:20%;left:0%">
```